# How to configure settings.php to make a second database available to the Feeds module

Tags: database, feeds

I feel like this is a basic set up question, but can't find an answer anywhere.

I am running Drupal 7.3.50 and using the CiviCRM module for managing contacts.  The CiviCRM database is separate, but on the same server.

I want to be able to create Drupal nodes from organisation data in CiviCRM, so need to read the org data into Drupal.  The Feeds module says that it does this very thing even from external databases, citing two possibilities, the Feeds SQL and Feeds Database sub-modules.

I have two questions:

1. Feeds SQL says it can read data from any database configured in settings.php.  I have configured my civi database as best I can according the instructions in settings.php for using multiple databases, but Feeds SQL can't find the new tables, presumably because it can't find the new database.

My configuration of settings.php looks like:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'simeonne_drupal',
      'username' => 'simeonne',
      'password' => '********',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
'civicrm' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'simeonne_civicrm',
      'username' => 'simeonne',
      'password' => '********',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

It doesn't cause any errors that I have discovered, but doesn't seem to be recognised by Feeds SQL.

My question is how do I configure settings.php to work with Feeds SQL?

2. I installed Feeds Database hoping for a bit more user friendly instruction, went through the configuration procedure for a new 'Feeds importer' and nowhere along the way did it ask for any information about the external database, name, server, driver, or SQL query to run.  Nothing.

My question then is how do I configure Feeds Database?

I think these two questions are related which is why I have presumed to ask them in a single post, but I am happy to be disabused of that presumption and create a second post.

Thanks,
Lewis